# Convert laravel morph collection to model collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have 3 models:

`Post`, `Like`, `Trending`

The like and trending models are polymorphs, both are:

```
public function likeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

public function trendingable()
  {
      return $this->morphTo();
  }
```

When I populate the trendings table based on the likes the only way to access the "posts" from a trending collection is to make a foreach loop like this:

```
$chart = Trending::all();

foreach($chart as $chartItem)
{
   $chartItem->trendingable->title
}
```

How can I convert the `$chart` collection into `posts` collection without the foreach loop? I am using Laravel 5.8

Comment: `$chart = Trending::with('trendingable')->get();` I haven't used morph relationships, but can you do this and show me whether it gives all data with `trendingable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should always define the opposite of the relation:

```
public Post extends Model
{
public function trendings()
{
return $this->morphMany('App\Trending', 'trendingable');
}
}
```

now if you want to get all posts that have trendings with their trendings:

```
$postWithTrending=Post::with('trendings')->whereHas('trendings')->get();
```

if you had to get them by Trending model:

```
$chart = Trending::where('trendingable_model','=',Post::class)->with
('trendingable')->get()->pluck('trendingable');
```

but that won't get a list of posts model but array represent posts as key value pairs